# How to auto-populate a New child record's lookup field with a parent's field while creating

Tags: parent

I am creating a new child record with a lookup field which I want to be populated automatically upon pressing the "New" button. It would be the equivalent as when the linking field between the parent/child is automatically populated to indicate the parent.

I need it to be populated automatically upfront (not done using a post-create) so other code can use the value of that lookup field to create lists which the user can see while filling out the record.

How is this done ? I almost feel like I'm missing something because it seems like it should be easy. Ideally, it would be just a simple as creating a formula field to reference other fields of the parent, but apparently you cannot reference the parent record until after the child record is saved.

Comment: Are you talking about overriding the New button with a custom Visualforce page?  What is the "other code" that needs to use the value of that lookup field?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by ensuring that the relationship between parent and child is master detail.

There is another method that involved overriding the new button using URL hacking. 
This method is [explained here](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/) and I have included the relevant text for historical reasons.

> To populate a Lookup value we need the field ID as before but this
>   time we need to add CF to the front of the ID so it looks something
>   like this – CF00Ni000000EpsgO. This is required when populating a
>   custom lookup field.  The first part to populate a lookup value is to
>   grab the name of the record we are populating. So using the method
>   before but with the added CF you can expect your button URL to look
>   like this
>
> /a0U/e?CF00Ni000000EpsgO={!Opportunity.Name} The next step is to grab
>   the ID of the record we wish to populate. This time though, we are
>   going to add “_lkid” to the end of our field ID (plus the CF we added
>   on earlier). This lkid parameter is telling Salesforce this is a
>   lookup field. So it looks a bit like this.
>
> /a0U/e?CF00Ni000000EpsgO={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Ni000000EpsgO_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}

Comment: Some questions : Is the Opportunity the parent in your scenario ? Also - I don't understand how you were able to get the child record ID before it was saved. I'm also confused on other parts. In your example you say you need a "field ID". I don't understand why you need to have ...EpsgO = {Opportunity.Name} - and then ...EpsgO_lkid = {Opportunity.id}. I guess I just don't quite understand what is being done there.

Comment: @Zoom_v It is further explained in the related article.

Answer (score 1):

based on the discussion It sounds like you want to create the "parent and child in a single DML statement" and there are plenty of articles for achieving that. Youre going to have to create a unique External Id text field on both the parent and the child object. Then you carefully relate them that way. Thats the only way (to my knowledge without multiple DML statements) to insert a child and relate it to a record whose ID does not yet exist